# Why is free energy in an isothermal process equivalent to the external work supplied to the system?

Tags: energy

Why is free energy in an isothermal process equivalent to the external work supplied to the system?

Answer (score 3):

Hope you're familiar with a small change in Helmholtz free energy, $F$, expressed in terms of small changes in its 'natural variables'…$$dF=-pdV-SdT.$$
Because your change is isothermal, $dT=0$. And $-pdV$ is the work done on the system, is it not? Not much more to be said (except that it's the *change* in free energy that's equal to the isothermal work done on the system).

Comment: Is it illustrative or helpful to talk about systems undergoing a first-order phase change as an exception to the rule, so that the the importance of the coupling of internal energy to temperature is emphasized?